# Where to report a suspected serial downvote?

Tags: support

I got home today and found about 8 of my questions downvoted. Statistically speaking, it's unusual. Those are good questions with multiple upvotes since before. The subject set is also a bit spread so I can exclude the likelihood of a grumpy, tired developer following paths within the same area.

Where do I report such?

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Yes and no. I know what happened. And I'm aware of the scripts. However, those don't trigger on downvote that isn't very extensive and timely more spread than a few minutes. And most importantly - I care more about the user doing that getting told not to, than my rep getting a slight hit. It's below the site's dignity to allow that. I put waaay to much effort in authoring well-formulated questions to accept that someone's letting their irritation urinate all over my babies, hehe. (A bit of a joke but still, that's how most serious users feel.)

Comment: Konrad duplicate is duplicate. We shouldn't write up meta posts for every single thing that bothers us. Wait for when the script isn't run, and you did flag for moderator attention but didn't get any results, which would be 4 days later. Then you can possibly ask on meta if you want.

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Oh, I totally agree with you on that. I'm worried that such misbehavior is going to deteriorate the value of the site in then long run (as it already partially has), especially given that the community isn't acting on it very often. Now, I hardly nag about every single thing on Meta and I can't see how this is a dupe. However, I'm going to do the "be like Bill" thing - you know. Just go and do other stuff, hehe. Cheers.

Comment: The community isn't acting on this very often since 90% of the time it's dealt with automatically and the rest is dealt with by mods privately. :)

Comment: This looks like it might have already fixed itself.

Comment: Related question and answer from StackExchange Meta http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126829/273494